# Extract Stata matrix element by column name

Tags: stata

I would like to read off Stata matrix elements by column name so that I can loop over a `varlist` after running a regression.

In the following code it works sometimes, but not all the time. And I can't figure out why.

```
sysuse auto, clear
scalar drop _all
matrix drop _all

regress price weight headroom trunk
matrix b = e(b)
local colnames : colnames b
foreach v of local colnames {
    if ("`v'" != "_cons") {
        display "-------------------------"
        display "`v'"
        quietly summarize `v', detail
        scalar beta = b[1,`v']
        scalar p75 = `r(p75)'
        scalar p25 = `r(p25)'
        scalar iqr = p75 - p25
        scalar effect = beta * iqr
        scalar dir
    }
}
```

It fails for `weight` and `trunk`, but not `headroom`. Both `weight` and `trunk` are negative, but in my own separate code it fails for positive coefficients.

**Using a manual counter works (below), but why does it fail with column names? Is there another solution?**

```
regress price weight headroom trunk
matrix b = e(b)
local colnames : colnames b
local i = 1 
foreach v of local colnames {
    if ("`v'" != "_cons") {
        display "-------------------------"
        display "`v'"
        quietly summarize `v', detail
        scalar beta = b[1,`i']
        local ++i
        scalar p75 = `r(p75)'
        scalar p25 = `r(p25)'
        scalar iqr = p75 - p25
        scalar effect = beta * iqr
        scalar dir
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See `help matrix subscripting` for an explanation of why your attempt at subscripting using column names didn't work. Replacing your line with

```
        scalar beta = b[1,colnumb(b,"`v'")]
```

does work.

Comment: Thanks, but from `help matrix sub scripting` it isn't clear. Is it the mixture of numbers and text? In the help file they show text sub scripting. In any case, this works! Thanks!

Comment: Also, the above works in my toy code, but in some cases I get the following error. `type mismatch r(109);`

Comment: In `help matrix subscripting` the second sentence of the description is _Subscripting by row/column name may only be used in a matrix context._ The `scalar` command is not a matrix command. Note that column and row names must be a `string`, so the `"quotation marks"`surrounding the macro expansion are required, and this is true not only in `colnumb' but also in other matrix expressions. When I was writing my initial advice, I encountered this when I was trying to narrow down the problem, so I expect you have used an unquoted column name.